# Laravel - filter result from another sql table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

now I have function for grabbing events (it will give participant id also), but I have another table as
participant_data  with participant_id and I need filter by status them

```php
    public function eventSearch(Request $request)
    {
        return ParticipantEvent::with('participant')
        ->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
        ->get()
        ->map(function($event) {
        $event->url = route('public::participant::show', ['participant' => $event->participant]);
        $participant = collect($event->participant->toArray())->all();  
            return $event;
        });
    }
```

I got solution to get the participants, with statuses:

```php
    $participants = Participant::where(
        function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas(
                'participantElections',
                function ($subQuery) {
                    $subQuery->where('status', '=', 'good');
                }
            )
        }
    )->get();
    return $participants;
```

But how to combine this 2 solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might need to add a closure filter on `with()` clause

```
ParticipantEvent::with([
'participant' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas(
                'participantElections',
                function ($subQuery) {
                    $subQuery->where('status', '=', 'good');
                }
            )
        }
    ])
    ->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
    ->get()
```